# How can I set data from a listView in the corresponding columns?

Tags: java, android, listview, arraylist

I have payment list. I won't show my data in columns.

[Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jv91U.png)

I have method

```
public String paymentDescription()
{
    return "Index"+paymentIndex+"Principal "+paymentPrincipal +" Interest "+paymentInterest+" Total "+paymentTotal();
}
```

All of them show me in one line. I would like to display the appropriate dataset in the corresponding column.

Comment: I want to display my column in Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

You need to learn the difference between return and println. This is one way to do it.

```
System.out.println("Index " + "Principal " + "Interest " + "Total");
System.out.println(paymentIndex + " " + paymentPrincipal + " " + paymentInterest + " " + paymentTotal);
```

You could also use `\n` this will create a new line for you. I would use println over return anyway though. You will need to change your signature from String to void.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are using a ListView, I think you need to look into building a Custom ListView. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848662/multicolumn-listview-android) for a similar question with an answer.